# jest.mock on React Functional component - nothing was returned from render

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I use clean Create React App instance with React Testing library

```
$ npx create-react-app test-app
...
$ npm install --save @testing-library/react @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Then I create simple Functional Component

./Chleb.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Chleb = () => <div>chleb</div>;

export default Chleb;
```

In default App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chleb from "./Chleb";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Chleb />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

then, in the App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render  } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./Chleb');

describe('<App /> tests', () => {
  it('Should render the component correctly', () => {
    const {container} = render(<App/>);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

What yields:

```
Error: Chleb(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I think that either Jest or RTL is not supporting arrow functions?

That's really strange, but when I convert Chleb.js to old React Class component, it works correctly.
It also works, when I provide manual `fn` mock implementation in the `jest.mock('...', fn)`.

Is it required to provide manual mock implementation for React Functional components, or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hey @Anders no, We went with manual mocking for all of the modules :(

Answer (score 0):

try setting resetMocks as false in jest config